# Minikube MetalLb addon Imagepullbackoff

Tags: minikube, metallb

I am trying to enable the metallb addon but I keep getting Imagepullbackoff errors.
**Output of kubectl describe pod controller_pod**

```
Name:             controller-644c846477-pkvb7
Namespace:        metallb-system
Priority:         0
Service Account:  controller
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Sat, 25 Mar 2023 11:27:29 +0000
Labels:           app=metallb
                  component=controller
                  pod-template-hash=644c846477
Annotations:      prometheus.io/port: 7472
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:           Pending
IP:               10.244.0.31
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.31
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/controller-644c846477
Containers:
  controller:
    Container ID:  
    Image:         docker.io/metallb/controller:v0.9.6@sha256:fbfdb9d3f55976b0ee38f3309d83a4ca703efcf15d6ca7889cd8189142286502
    Image ID:      
    Port:          7472/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      --port=7472
      --config=config
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ImagePullBackOff
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  100Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     100Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-q88bm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-q88bm:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:              kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  17m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned metallb-system/controller-644c846477-pkvb7 to minikube
  Normal   Pulling    15m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/metallb/controller:v0.9.6@sha256:fbfdb9d3f55976b0ee38f3309d83a4ca703efcf15d6ca7889cd8189142286502"
  Warning  Failed     15m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/metallb/controller:v0.9.6@sha256:fbfdb9d3f55976b0ee38f3309d83a4ca703efcf15d6ca7889cd8189142286502": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for metallb/controller, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed     15m (x4 over 17m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     15m (x6 over 17m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m15s (x65 over 17m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "docker.io/metallb/controller:v0.9.6@sha256:fbfdb9d3f55976b0ee38f3309d83a4ca703efcf15d6ca7889cd8189142286502"
```

I have tried running `eval $(minikube -p myprofile docker-env)` and pulling the images themselves but to no avail.
docker.io/metallb/speaker:v0.9.6
docker.io/metallb/controller:v0.9.6

Comment: By chance do you have a namespace called **docker.io**?

Comment: I do not have a namespace called docker.io but I am using the docker driver

Comment: Can you try this command `$ minikube image ls --format table` and see whether you have the `docker.io/metallb/controller` image.

Comment: It seemed that there was an issue with where they were pulling the metallb images which was fixed in https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/16053. I built minikube from this pr and was able to install metallb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now there is a fix for this issue in minikube that hasn't been introduced into a new release yet.

To use metallb build minikube from the main branch of the [minikube github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube)
Follow this [guide](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/contrib/building/binaries/) to make the new minikube build.

You should be able to enable the addon now.